# Can't run confusion matrix in R

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I am trying to run a confusion matrix in R for my decision tree model but get the following error:

> "Error in table(data, reference, dnn = dnn, ...) : all arguments must have the same length"

I don't understand why it wont run.

```
dtree_test <- rpart(writeoff ~ education+employ_status+residential_status+loan_amount+loan_length+
                      net_income,method="class", data=testnew,parms=list(split="information"))
dtree_test$cptable

plotcp(dtree_test)

dtree_test.pruned <- prune(dtree_test, cp=.01`enter code here`639344)
prp(dtree_test.pruned, type = 2, extra = 104,
    fallen.leaves = TRUE, main="Decision Tree")
dtree_test.pred <- predict(dtree_test.pruned, testnew, type="class")

dtree_test.perf <- table(testnew$writeoff, dtree_test.pred,
                         dnn=c("Actual", "Predicted"))
dtree_test.perf
confusionMatrix(predict(dtree_test.pruned, testnew, type="class"),train$writeoff)
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line is:

```r
confusionMatrix(predict(dtree_test.pruned, testnew, type="class"),train$writeoff)
```

which makes predictions for dataset `testnew` but compares those with the response in dataset `train`.

Also in `rpart(...)` you have `data=testnew` but perhaps you meant to use your training data to fit the model?